# How to Convert Hijri date to Gregorian and Hijri date to Gregorian vice versa using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

We have two [Hijiri and English ] datepicker text boxes when given date into hijiri it will convert to Gregorian

Comment: See this simple code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/convert-any-of-the-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world-calenda

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you to use a robust solution tested for that.
I'd use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/hijri/) in pair with a Hijiri plugin (https://github.com/xsoh/moment-hijri )

Once you have those plugin; manipulating a date from one side to other is very simple.
See documentation for more info of the hijri plugin : https://github.com/xsoh/moment-hijri